# Why does 32-bit Windows impose a 2 GB process address space limit, but 64-bit Windows impose a 4GB limit?

Tags: memory, operating-systems

I get that `2^32 = 4,294,967,296` and 2GB is for the OS and 2GB is for the process, but why does a 64 bit OS only give 4GB of address space? Should it not be `2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615` which when divided evenly amongst the OS and process is **a lot** more than 4 GB?

Comment: You should clarify that you're talking about the address space available to 32-bit processes. 64-bit processes have access to much more than 4GB of address space.

Comment: A 32-bit application on a 64-bit operating system is subject to exactly the same limitations as a 32-bit application on a 32-bit operating system, all the operating system structures required by the 32-bit application are the same. The only applications that see true benefits with 64-bit are the operating system itself and 64-bit applications.

Answer (score 10):

If you look at **[Memory Limits for Windows Releases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)**

The limit for x64 user mode virtual address space is not `4GB` but at least `8TB`

[Some explanation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2008/11/17/3155406.aspx) that justifies the `8Tb` limit.

By default a 32bit exe is limited to `2GB` on 64bit os as well unless it is tweaked with `IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE`

Comment: Note that 64-bit processes must set IMAGE_FILE_LARGE_ADDRESS_AWARE in their PE header to get that much user mode virtual address space, otherwise they're limited to 2 GB like 32-bit processes.

Answer (score 5):

2^32 (4GB) is the maximum amount of address space that can be addressed at one time with 32-bit pointers. So a 32-bit process is necessarily limited to an address space of 4GB, because it uses 32-bit pointers, regardless of OS.

Note that this is purely a restriction on *virtual* memory that a process can have mapped into its address space at one time.

Comment: why is 2 gig the limit? a 32 bit pointer can address 4 gigs of memory directly. I read a page that said you have to be careful doing pointer math on pointers with the high bit set, but other than that, why would there be a limit of 2 gig? Nobody seems to know "WHY?"

Comment: The kernel needs some address space, and it's ugly to use separate address spaces.

Comment: from what I read it was to protect programmers from accidentally doing signed pointer math and getting unexpected results if one pointer had the high bit set and the other did not. Windows does not NEED 2 gigs of address space. What do you mean its ugly to use separate address space? That's what virtual memory is for.

Comment: That's the reason 32-bit processes are limited to 2GB on 64-bit editions of Windows, unless they specifically indicate that it is safe to give them a 4GB address space. 32-bit Windows does need at least 1GB of kernel address space and uses 2GB by default. It would be too complex to explain here why popular 32-bit operating systems (including Windows and Linux) don't give their kernel a separate address space and instead use a user/kernel split, but the short reason is that it makes it very complex for kernel code to interact with user space.

Comment: Can you point me to a webpage? I mean if the mmu does mapping of virtual addresses to physical addresses, and things like PAE allow you to page to more than 4 gig of memory anyway, and everything in memory can be shifted around on a whim, why does the OS have any harder time than user space applications?

Comment: The main reason is that if the kernel had its own address space, the TLB would have to be flushed on every kernel/user transition. Also, all data copied between kernel and user space would require remapping or windowing operations.

Comment: okay, I think I get it, but then don't all the user applications have the same problem context switching between themselves (the user application) and the kernel calls they make, since the applications have their own address space, that aren't the same as each other?

Comment: @Stu No. There are two types of kernel code, code that cares which process's memory is mapped into the user space portion and code that doesn't. For code that doesn't, it doesn't matter. For code that does, it's almost always going to need the current process anyway. For calls like `read` or `write`, it's the current process's memory that holds the data anyway.

Comment: let me take that back, I forgot we were talking about 32 bit environments here.

Comment: gotchya, okay, makes sense, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score -2):

Your calculations are correct. Running a 64 bit system you don't need to worry about the address space (its much more than your system will support). If the RAM size isn't what it is supposed to be, the problem lays somewhere else. Perhaps your mainboard is limiting or some of the ram sticks are not supported/broken.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: That's alright -- the OP likely didn't understand the answer.